# XSL: get xml elements into another node

Tags: xslt

I have this xml, and a problem with the xslt transform:

```
<start>
    <row>
        <xxx Caption="School1"></xxx>
        <yyy Caption="Subject1"></yyy>
        <zzz></zzz>
    </row>
    <row>
        <xxx Caption="School2"></xxx>
        <yyy Caption="Subject2"></yyy>
        <zzz></zzz>
    </row>
</start>
```

The Xsl-transform is like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <schools>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//row/*" />
        </schools>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//row/*">
        <school>
            <xsl:if test="name()='xxx'">
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Caption"/>
                </name>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="name()='yyy'">
                <subject>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Caption"/>
                </subject>
            </xsl:if>
        </school>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xsl transform gives this result, which is not exactly what i want it to be:

```
<schools>
    <school>
        <name>School1</name>
    </school>
    <school>
        <subject>Subject1</subject>
    </school>
    <school />
    <school>
        <name>School2</name>
    </school>
    <school>
        <subject>Subject2</subject>
    </school>
    <school />
</schools>
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
<schools>
    <school>
        <name>School1</name>
        <subject>Subject1</subject>
    </school>
    <school>
        <name>School2</name>
        <subject>Subject2</subject>
    </school>
</schools>
```

The name and subject elements should be inside the same school element.

Please help me for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/start">
    <schools>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </schools>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <school>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xxx | yyy"/>
    </school>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xxx">
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Caption"/>
    </name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="yyy">
    <subject>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Caption"/>
    </subject>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```